# How to go back to the old input system?

Tags: unity, input

I have tried using Unity's new input system, but it's incredibly hard to learn, the documentation is poor, and the old system is much easier to work with.  I would like to revert my project back to the old system, but I am unsure how to do that.  How do i disable the package and reconfigure my project so it will accept code using the old system?

Answer (score 1):

If you write the old input system, in code, then unity's code checker will automatically update it for you. If unity doesn't automatically then in the menus up top press Assets->Run API Updater. Hope this helps.

Comment: will this disable the package?

Comment: @Millard What are you trying to do with the input system? Just simple keypresses: `if (Input.GetKeyDown("W");`, or something else?

Comment: So far I've only used *Input.GetAxis()*.  Unfortunately I won't be able to test anything yet, I currently don't have access to the project.

Comment: @Millard test it in a new project?

Comment: `Input.GetAxis();` is what i always use. I haven't used the new input system at all. The new input system requires less coding, but it's more confusing for me/

Comment: It doesn't help that there is 4 different ways of scripting the input, and every tutorial is using a different one.  Apparently a lot of people think its a mess.  Apparently it makes it easier to script rebinding of controlls and stuff, but I'm not sure if it's worth it untill they make it better.

Comment: Unreal's is easier, but I like unity better, especially since I've only been programming for a year 1/2.

Comment: Unreal's input is definitely easier, but it uses C++ which makes programming a lot more difficult.

Comment: i know c++, but i prefer c#

Answer (score 1):

In order to revert back
Go to **player** settings and select **Active input handling** dropdown.

[image]
[**Watch 43 Second Tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjCipOTnWAg)